# Three joined tables, need one query response

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've struggled with this query for a long time and would really appreciate any advice. Given the following SQL example tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
(
    [First] VARCHAR(10),
    [Last] VARCHAR(10),
    [Priority] INT
)

INSERT INTO #Table1 ([First], [Last], [Priority]) 
VALUES ('My', 'Name', '1'), ('Her', 'Name', '1'), ('His', 'Name', '1');

CREATE TABLE #Table2
(
    [First] VARCHAR(10),
    [Last] VARCHAR(10),
    [Priority] INT 
)

INSERT INTO #Table2 ([First], [Last], [Priority]) 
VALUES ('My', 'Name', '2'), ('Her', 'Name', '2'), ('His', 'Name', '2');


CREATE TABLE #Table3
(
    [First] VARCHAR(10),
    [Last] VARCHAR(10),
    [Priority] INT 
)

INSERT INTO #Table3 ([First], [Last], [Priority]) 
VALUES ('My', 'Name', '3'), ('Her', 'Name', '3'), ('His', 'Name', '3');
```

I'm trying to query only a single record for each name from the table with the highest priority. The following query returns all names from all tables, not the desired results.

```
SELECT 
    [First], [Last], [Priority] 
FROM
    (SELECT [First], [Last], [Priority] 
     FROM #Table1 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT [First], [Last], [Priority] 
     FROM #Table2 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT [First], [Last], [Priority] 
     FROM #Table3) D3
ORDER BY 
    [Priority] DESC
```

Query results are not what is needed like this:

```
First   Last    Priority
------------------------
My      Name      3
Her     Name      3
His     Name      3
My      Name      2
Her     Name      2
His     Name      2
My      Name      1
Her     Name      1
His     Name      1
```

I've tried filtering out the lower priority table values using TOP 1, DISTINCT, MAX(Priority). But never got the following desired results.

```
First   Last    Priority
------------------------
My      Name       3
Her     Name       3
His     Name       3
```

Thank you in advance for taking the time to review my question and any advice or guidance you might provide.

Cheers,
Gene

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Most straightforward is probably `DENSE_RANK()` but it won't work on older versions

Comment: SQL Version 13 offline but Azure SQL online. I've marked Tsvetelin answer because it returns the correct results. However, I'll look into Nick's `DENSE_RANK()` suggestion as well. Thank you.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` as posted in the other answer is along the same lines. They are all valid answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select First, Last, max(priority) from xxx group by First,Last

That should work.

```
SELECT 
    [First], [Last], max([Priority])
FROM
    (SELECT [First], [Last], [Priority] 
 FROM #Table1 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT [First], [Last], [Priority] 
 FROM #Table2 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT [First], [Last], [Priority] 
 FROM #Table3) D3
GROUP BY First, Last
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function make row number by `[First]`  `[Last]` columns then get first row.

```
SELECT [First], [Last], [Priority]  
FROM (
    SELECT [First], [Last], [Priority],ROW_number() over(partition by [First], [Last] order by Priority desc) rn
    FROM
    (
       SELECT [First], [Last], [Priority] FROM #Table1 UNION ALL
       SELECT [First], [Last], [Priority] FROM #Table2 UNION ALL
       SELECT [First], [Last], [Priority] FROM #Table3
    ) D3
) t1
where rn = 1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8d5785ef826b35ff84b4e8153d638351)